# Updating array in a function causes pointer lose

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, global

I am trying to divide my code into functions, I have a sample code of "Game Of Life".
However, when I try to initialize 2D grid array in a function, gnuplot gives no valid data points error.

These are global variables declared before main:

```
static char **currWorld=NULL, **nextWorld=NULL
```

This is the original logic to init game grid, but this part is in main.

```
if (game == 0){ // Use Random input
    for(i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<ny-1;j++) {
            currWorld[i][j] = (real_rand() < prob);
            population[w_plot] += currWorld[i][j];
        }
    }
}
else if (game == 1){ //  Block, still life
    printf("2x2 Block, still life\n");
    int nx2 = nx/2;
    int ny2 = ny/2;
    currWorld[nx2+1][ny2+1] = currWorld[nx2][ny2+1] = currWorld[nx2+1][ny2] = currWorld[nx2][ny2] = 1;
    population[w_plot] = 4;
}
else if (game == 2){ //  Glider (spaceship)
    printf("Glider (spaceship)\n");
    // Your code codes here
}
else {
    printf("Unknown game %d\n",game);
    exit(-1);
}
```

This is my function:

```
  int init_game(int choice, int probability){

    int i,j;
    if (choice == 0){ // Use Random input
        for(i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
            for(j=1;j<ny-1;j++) {
                currWorld[i][j] = (real_rand() < probability);
                population[w_plot] += currWorld[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 1){ //  Block, still life
        printf("2x2 Block, still life\n");
        int nx2 = nx/2;
        int ny2 = ny/2;
        currWorld[nx2+1][ny2+1] = currWorld[nx2][ny2+1] = currWorld[nx2+1][ny2] = currWorld[nx2][ny2] = 1;
        population[w_plot] = 4;
    }
    else if (choice == 2){ //  Glider (spaceship)
        printf("Glider (spaceship)\n");
        // Your code codes here
    }
    else {
        printf("Unknown game %d\n",choice);
        exit(-1);
    } 
}
```

and my function call in main:

```
init_game(game, prob);
```

value of game is 0, prob is 0.2 and I tested memory allocations and other stuff, they work fine.
Only difference is I moved the logic to a function. How can this happen? My arrays are global, I cannot understand how it cannot be initialized.

This is the gnuplot error:

```
Skipping data file with no valid points
```

Since gnuplot and other functions are works fine, I did not add them but if you need any info, I can add.

Here is the link of file itself:

[file](https://gofile.io/?c=mZIYoE)

Comment: The `nx` seems to come from nowhere in your function. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: nx is the column and row size of arrays

Comment: Yes but they could be globals which initialized 0 and later defined in main or not, which could cause the issue. Hard to tell anything without the whole code.

Comment: you are right, I added as a link to file, there is no problem with MeshPilot btw, I can simulate correctly with that.

Comment: Provide a [mre] in the question itself, not as a link.